# Visual Basic sum and average calculation

Tags: vb.net, average, calculation

So this part I have for average does not work...

```
For Each s As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfileishere")
    Dim testScore As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = s.Count
    If Integer.TryParse(s, testScore) Then
        averageWeight = s.Count / s
    End If
Next
AverageKgTextBox.Text = averageWeight.ToString
```

I have the maximum working but not the minimum which this is the code for and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
Dim lowestWeight As Integer = 0
For Each s As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile")
    Dim testScore As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(s, testScore) Then
        lowestWeight = Math.Min(lowestWeight, testScore)
    End If
Next
LowestKgTextBox.Text = lowestWeight.ToString
```

Again these all have to read from the textfile and give the output, I would like to code this in the simplest manner possible.

Comment: Use a variable, Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfileishere").  Now you'll have much better odds avoiding the nonsensical s.Count and use lines.Length.

Comment: The first thing to do is set Option Strict on. It will save you from countless runtime errors. To turn on Option Strict on the Menu bar select Tools -> Options. In the left hand panel of the Options dialog, choose Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. Now, under Default project settings, set the drop down box next to Option Strict to On.

Comment: Let's forget programming for a minute and try to get the arithmetic straight. Sum / Count = Average

Comment: Saying that it "does not work" tells us nothing!  Please provide more detail about the actual problem you are experiencing?  What data did you supply to the method and what was its output?  What did you expect the output to be?  What did you observe when you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate average in visual basic code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453146/how-to-calculate-average-in-visual-basic-code)

Answer (score 2):

For the average calculation:

I won't give the full answer but you should first increment the sum and count in the "for each" loop, then calculate the average outside of the loop. When you are doing `s.Count` you are counting the characters in the string, this is not what you want.

For the minimum calculation:

The lowestWeight is initialized to zero so if your test scores are positive, the minimum will always be 0. Initialize it with a very high value like this:

```
Dim lowestWeight As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
```

Tip for both cases: step through your code with the debugger. You will see how your code behaves, and if it behaves as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

For sum its as simple as this:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or (TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter number.")
    Else
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        sum = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
        MessageBox.Show("the sum is: " & sum)
    End If
End Sub
```